# save(), unexpected behavior

Tags: r, save

I'm trying to save the variables from a function call via save()

```
f <- function(x) {
  r <- x - g(x)
  r
}
g <- function(y) {
  r <- y * h(y)
  r
}
h <- function(z) {
  save(list = ls(all = TRUE), file = "hello.RData", envir = parent.frame())
  r <- log(z)
  if (r < 10)
    r^2
  else r^3
}
```

This however returns the error "object z not found", even though according to the documentation parent.frame() is the standard value for envir.

```
save(list = ls(all = TRUE), file = "hello.RData", envir = sys.frame())
```

Does not work either

```
save(list = ls(all = TRUE), file = "hello.RData")
```

This works. But it is kind of a mystery for me what envir actually is if not the standard value given in the documentation.

What is the reason for the error and why is the parent frame the standard enviroment to be looked at in save()?

Comment: While I understand there's scoping going on here, your function `h` works just fine in the sense that the corrrect value is returned.  You should make it clear that what didn't work is saving the internal variables to your `.rdata` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to note is that there is a difference between where default values for functions are evaluated and where values that you pass in are evaluated. Consider

```
ff<-function(a, b=a+2) {print(b)}

ff(2);
# [1] 4
ff(2, a+2);
# Error in print(b) : object 'a' not found
```

Despite the fact that the "default" for `b` is `a+2` we can't just pass in `a+2` because it needs to be evaluated in a different context.

Here's another example

```
gg<-function(a) {
    ff(2, match.call());
}

ff<-function(a, b=match.call()) {
    print(b)
}

ff(2);
# ff(a = 2)
gg(2)
# gg(a = 2);
```

Despite the fact that `gg` passes the same "default value" to `ff`, we get a different behavior.

This is what's happening with `save(..., envir=parent.frame())`. When you call that function in `h()`, you are getting the frame from where `h()` was called, but if you don't specify an environment, when `save` calls `parent.frame()`, `save` will get the frame where `save()` was called from. If you want to explicily pass the *current* environment to `save()`, you could do

```
save(list = ls(all = TRUE), file = "hello.RData", envir=environment())
```

But this will basically do the same thing as not specifying the `envir=` parameter at all.

So the documentation is correct, it's just that the behavior is different depending who actually is calling `parent.frame()`.

Comment: As discussed in the R-inferno.

Answer (score 0):

This question has to do with **scoping**. For an indepth description of scoping check out this article http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping

First, by specifying envir=parent.frame() you are selecting the global environment. This is because your function is not defined within another function or object. For example, see the difference between printing the parent.frame in the two different h functions i define below.

```
!> h <- function(z){
 +     print(parent.frame())
 + }
 >
 >
 > h(10)
 <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
 >
 > h <- function(z){
 +     b <- function(){
 +         print(parent.frame())}
 +     b()
 + }
 >
 > h()
 <environment: 0x10f06b3c0>
```

I believe you either want to nest your functions inside each other (as shown above with functions h and b) or declare a 'global variable'. This is done by the

```
<<-
```

command

for instance:

```
 > h <- function(z) {
 +         r <<- log(z)
 +         if (r < 10){
 +                 r <<- r^2}
 +         else r<<- r^3
 +     }
 > h(1)
 > r
 [1] 0
 > h(10)
 > r
 [1] 5.301898
 > h(10000)
!> r
 [1] 84.83037
```